How to make a table row expand and fill remaining height while preserving rowspan cells?
Desired solution is script free and dynamic.



<style>
    table, td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tr:not(:last-child) {
        height: 0;
    }
    tr:last-child {
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Group 1</td>
    <td rowspan="999"><div style="height: 300px; width: 20px; background: #000;"></div></td>
    <td>Group 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Group 2</td>
    <td>Group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Group 3</td>
    <td>Group 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>



